Giving up fully-funded phd offers for masters?
I am a senior undergraduate student double majoring in Mechanical Engineering and Mathematics.
My current research interests are in turbulence, dynamical systems, and data-driven methods. This year, I've been applying to some PhD programs both in ME and Applied Mathematics. I do have a few offers that are fully funded and they are relatively good programs (About 40th in ranking). I was hoping that I could maybe get into top 30 but can't complain. Recently, I got offered no funding MS mathematics program at NYU Courant, and I am very much interested in it because given that my research interests lie in applied mathematics, this degree can really help me get into more prestigious phd programs. Any advice on this??
Edit: I know research alignment matters more than ranking. But I did have other labs that are perfectly aligned with my interests but ranked higher than the options I have. Those were actually my top choices as well. So I want to have a second shot at those programs after building a stronger profile.

That really does not sound like a good plan, but it is a personal decision that you have to make. The difference between top 40 and top 30 is ill defined in the first place, and not worth worrying about in the second place.

Being a grad student is hard. Being a grad student without funding is very hard. I had (not a lot of) funding during my master's (because I was international). Multiple times in grad school I ran out of money at the end of the month, and my mental health took a serious tumble. I resorted to peanut butter sandwiches for multiple meals in a row for a few months.

Just to add that, while NYU is a great school, New York is a very expensive city, making it even harder to get along without funding.
